# Existence of solution to this PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation, elliptic-operators

Let $\Sigma$ be a compact surface and denote by $\nu$ the unit conormal for $\partial \Sigma$. Let

$$E = \left\{ \phi \in C^{2,\alpha}(\Sigma) : \int_{\Sigma} \phi \, \mathrm{d}A = 0 \right\} $$
and
$$F = \left\{ \phi \in C^{0,\alpha}(\Sigma) : \int_{\Sigma} \phi \, \mathrm{d}A = 0 \right\},$$

for fixed $0 < \alpha < 1$.

I would like to know why, given $(f,g) \in F \times C^{1,\alpha}(\partial \Sigma)$, the problem

$$\begin{cases} -\Delta_{\Sigma} u = f + \frac{1}{\vert \Sigma \vert} \int_{\partial \Sigma} g \, \mathrm{d}L, \quad \text{on } \Sigma \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = -g, \quad \text{on } \partial \Sigma
\end{cases}$$

has a solution in $E$. This came up for me in a paper. I am sorry if the question is silly, but I am not very good at PDE's.

Comment: crossposted - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336766/why-does-this-pde-have-a-solution